# Fastest way to create a custom Facebook fan page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

Now that FBML is no longer available, I have to create an app via Facebook's developer portal, obtain an API ID though I don't really need it. If all I am doing is making a generic HTML fan page, and then add a tab to the sidebar, is there an cleaner & quicker way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a fan page and add the FBML app to it. You can add the FBML app going to the following link:

https://www.facebook.com/add.php?api_key=fdfd01c9df7d644a68a4e989ae861e44&pages=1

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks RP. It's a fast tool to add FBML without creating an app. However the tab doesn't show on the left after the FBML page is added to the fan page. : (

Comment: Yes, it appears as a tab of the Fan Page. Go to the link, select the page you want to add to. Wait the page load and click on Add Static FBML. It will create a tab called FBML on your page.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the HTML page then I don't know where is your problem?

You are aware that FBML is no longer used so you need to put your HTML page somewhere on your server, point to it from the App settings "Page Tab" section under Facebook Integration and you are good to go.